# Get int value from SQLite database table

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt5

I'm trying to get a value from a column in my table. I know that the query will only return one result, and I need an `int` value...

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("select Position from workers where Username='"+username+"'and Password='"+password+"'");
qry.exec();
int status = qry.value(0).toInt();
```

But this doesn't work. In my table there is a field called Position which is `INTEGER`, so I'm trying to retrieve it.
Again, I know that this `qry` will only have one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `qry.next()` before accessing the result.

Check the return value to see whether your query returned anything at all.

You should definitly check out the examples at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html

Comment: It worked this way!
`qry.prepare(...); qry.exec(); qry.next(); status = qry.value(0).toInt();`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
while (qry.next()) 
{
   int status = qry.value(0).toInt();
}
```